# The book I read yesterday <is><was> this one

Tags: tense

(1) Mary said to Susan, "The book I read yesterday **is** this one."

(2) Mary said to Susan, "The book I read yesterday **was** this one."

[Question] Which is correct if Mary is holding the book in her hand?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Both forms are syntactically valid, and could reasonably be used even if Mary is holding or pointing to the book.

It's a stylistic choice reflecting whether you're identifying the book as...

> ***something which IS here now***
> or
> ***something which WAS read yesterday***